# Why does the turbulence not affect the particle system?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, force-fields

I want to make a smoke trail behind a flying object by emitting particles and make a smoke simulation with it. I parented a turbulence to the emitter so that the particles don't fly out too straight. But the turbulence doesn't affect the particles. And is it possible to emit the particles in smalle timesteps because when its moving so fast the particles are separated a lot from frame to frame...
[image: particles]

```
https://we.tl/t-MugEkhVqxR
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the *Strength* of your *Turbulence*. As for the slices of particules, instead of using a plane you could use a cuboid (juste extrude your plane to do it) and choose *Emission > Source > Emit From > Volume* (as it's already the case), here is what it would give:

[image]

But to have a similar effect you could just increase the velocity *Randomize* value:

[image]